# Information length and heat dissipation

Tags: thermodynamics, differential-geometry, information

I am trying to relate the information length of a path on a statistical manifold (according to the Fisher-Rao metric) to the heat dissipated, or work done, by moving a probability distribution along that path.

This should hopefully be straightforward given the relationship between information and energy, but I haven’t been able to solve it yet.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you looked at [this paper](https://journals.aps.org/prl/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevLett.99.100602) of Crooks?

Comment: I haven’t. This looks very useful, thanks!